# How to disable checkbox if it's checked when using checklist-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checklist-model

I'm using this `checklist-model` [directive](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) to loop through a list of checkboxes it can save objects to the database and can check the values that exist in `tabs` array in the `pop` object:
so the `pop` is the main object that has a property of array of `tabs`

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="25" flex="45" content-layout-align="center start" ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
    <md-checkbox checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab" >
        {{tab.name}}
    </md-checkbox>
</md-input-container>
```

I want to add a feature that if a checkbox is already selected then disable it, but my try ended up with disabling any checkbox that is selected (not only those already checked)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy:
in the initialize function (the function that get called when the page is loaded):

```
    const selectedIds = pop.tabs.map(x=>x.id);
    $scope.selectedIds = selectedIds;
```

and then added `ng-disabled` directive:

```
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
                    <md-checkbox checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab" ng-disabled="selectedIds.includes(tab.id)">
                        {{tab.name}}
                    </md-checkbox>
                </md-input-container>
```

I tried to make this outside the `initialize` method but the newly selected `id`s are added to the `tabs` array of the `pop` object.